# Java SQL Query freezing on createStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets, connection

I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL DB so I can test a couple queries for data load before making them into servlets.  The relevant code, with sensitive information removed:

```
String sqlURL, log, pass;

sqlURL = "jdbc:mysql://serveraddress";
log = "log";
pass = "pass";
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlURL, log, pass);
Statement s = c.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
```

Now, when I run this on a servlet, it works without problem.  However, if I try to run it locally in a java class, it freezes on `Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlURL, log, pass);` It doesn't crash, it just processes forever and doesn't establish the connection.  I was wondering what may be causing it and what I can do to correct it, because it's a lot easier to test and retest how much data is being returned and how long it takes to process from a local java class than from a servlet.

Comment: You could always wrap this with a timeout exception. That's what I normally do when making a connection outside - so that if it takes to long it will automatically cancel the operation and move on. If I had a guess, I'd bet its just waiting on the connection and the timeout is very long.

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql directly using those credentials from the machine running the local code?

Comment: I will try that Shadows.  
Yes I'm able to connect to mysql directly with the credentials I'm using.